# WebdriverIO ES6 PageObject method is not a function error

Tags: javascript, pageobjects, webdriver-io

I am attempting to define a PageObject using the syntax defined in the [WebdriverIO Docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html):

**Parent Page**

```
//page.js

export default class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.title = 'My Page';
  }

  open(path) {
    browser.url(path);
  }
}
```

**Child PageObject**

```
// login.page.js

import Page from './page';

class LoginPage extends Page {

  open() {
    super.open('/login');
  }
}

export default new LoginPage();
```

Then when I call the open method of the Login Page:

```
const LoginPage = require('../../pages/login.page');
LoginPage.open();
```

I get a `TypeError:`

```
TypeError: LoginPage.open is not a function
  [chrome #0-0]     at World.module.exports ...
  [chrome #0-0]     at Promise (<anonymous>)
  [chrome #0-0]     at F (/.../node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:35:28)
```

**Work around**
I can work around this problem by re-writing my PageObjects using `Object.create` rather than the class keyword (as described in the above linked docs).

Its not essential that I use the class keyword but I don't like to not knowing why this is failing. Please forgive me if it is obvious why this isn't working I am very new to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing ES6 and CommonJS syntax here. Change your test to use ES6 syntax and it should start working as you expect.

```
import LoginPage from '../../pages/login.page';

describe('login tests', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {        
        LoginPage.open();
    });

    it('should do something', () => {
        //do something
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for me

http://gelionprime.ml/2017/10/page-object-pattern-webdriverio/

**PARENT**

```
//page.js

class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.title = 'My Page';
  }

  open(path) {
    browser.url(path);
  }
}
module.exports = Page;
```

**CHILD**

```
// login.page.js

import Page from './page';

class LoginPage extends Page {

  open() {
    super.open('/login');
  }
}

module.exports = new LoginPage();
```

**test Spec file using page object**

```
const LoginPage = require('./login.page.js');
describe('test', () => {
    it('can open', () => {
        LoginPage.open();
    });
});
```